# Query msdb.dbo.sysssispackages XML for specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to query `msdb.dbo.sysssispackages` for active maintenance plans, and I can't wrap my head around how to query the XML in the `packagedata` column. I've found some other XML-related SQL questions on SO but so far nothing seems to quite fit what I'm looking for.

The XML in `msdb.dbo.sysssispackages.packagedata` looks like this:

```
<DTS:Executable DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DatabaseMaintenance.DbMaintenanceReindexTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.MaintenancePlanTasks, version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" DTS:ThreadHint="0">
      <DTS:Property DTS:Name="TaskContact">Rebuild Index Task; Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server v9; © 2004 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1</DTS:Property>
      <DTS:Property DTS:Name="LocaleID">-1</DTS:Property>
      <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">Rebuild Index Task</DTS:Property>
      <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{E4A9C2C8-F24F-4AE3-AC3D-F8B6729F1126}</DTS:Property>
      <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description">Rebuild Index Task</DTS:Property>
      <DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName">Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DatabaseMaintenance.DbMaintenanceReindexTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.MaintenancePlanTasks, version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91</DTS:Property>
      <DTS:EventHandler>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="EventID">0</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="EventName">OnPostExecute</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="LocaleID">-1</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{263C94D7-6FEC-4A4A-9EA1-2557E3892E74}</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName">OnPostExecute</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Variable>
          <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Namespace">System</DTS:Property>
          <DTS:Property DTS:Name="IncludeInDebugDump">6789</DTS:Property>
          <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">Propagate</DTS:Property>
          <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{DB1B0594-A0F1-4C48-867E-C5A9C6BB9322}</DTS:Property>
          <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description">The propagate property of the event</DTS:Property>
          <DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName" />
          <DTS:VariableValue DTS:DataType="11">0</DTS:VariableValue>
        </DTS:Variable>
      </DTS:EventHandler>
      <DTS:EventHandler>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="EventID">0</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="EventName">OnPreExecute</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="LocaleID">-1</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{AD9E11AB-D830-41A7-8A38-FC2E89B71FD1}</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName">OnPreExecute</DTS:Property>
        <DTS:Variable>
          <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Namespace">System</DTS:Property>
          <DTS:Property DTS:Name="IncludeInDebugDump">6789</DTS:Property>
          <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">Propagate</DTS:Property>
          <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{8A2A2399-1C88-4247-91E8-B87EB217F052}</DTS:Property>
          <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description">The propagate property of the event</DTS:Property>
          <DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName" />
          <DTS:VariableValue DTS:DataType="11">0</DTS:VariableValue>
        </DTS:Variable>
      </DTS:EventHandler>
      <DTS:ObjectData>
        <SQLTask:SqlTaskData xmlns:SQLTask="www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask" SQLTask:Connection="{8E20FB62-A80C-4A72-9789-C250348EDB1B}" SQLTask:DatabaseSelectionType="3" SQLTask:ServerVersion="10" SQLTask:ExtendedLogging="False" SQLTask:LocalConnectionForLogging="Local server connection" SQLTask:TaskName="" SQLTask:IgnoreDatabasesInNotOnlineState="False" SQLTask:UseOriginalAmount="True" SQLTask:Percentage="-1" SQLTask:Sort="False" SQLTask:KeepOnline="False" SQLTask:SkipUnsupported="False">
          <SQLTask:SelectedDatabases SQLTask:DatabaseName="AdventureWorks2008R2" />
        </SQLTask:SqlTaskData>
      </DTS:ObjectData>
    </DTS:Executable>
```

1. How do I find rows where `<DTS:Executable DTS:ExecutableType=` *contains* "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DatabaseMaintenance.DbMaintenanceReindexTask" like what is found in the first line in the xml?
2. How do I find the rows where `<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">A value here</DTS:Property>` *matches* a search string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [xquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx) to do this. Its a bit of a handful:

Point 1:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
(
    'www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' AS DTS
   ,'www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts/Tasks' AS SQLTask)
SELECT
  Nodes.node.value('(@DTS:ExecutableType)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS ExecutableType,
  Nodes.node.value('(DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="TaskContact"])[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS TaskContact
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
         CAST(CAST([packagedata] as varbinary(max)) as xml) PackageDataXml
    FROM      
         [msdb].[dbo].[sysssispackages]
  ) SysPackages
  CROSS APPLY 
    SysPackages.PackageDataXml.nodes('/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executable') Nodes(Node)
WHERE
  Nodes.node.value('@DTS:ExecutableType', 'varchar(100)') 
    LIKE 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DatabaseMaintenance.DbMaintenanceReindexTask%';
```

And for Point 2, the where clause is like so:

```
WHERE
  Nodes.node.value('(DTS:Property[@DTS:Name=''ObjectName''])[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
   = 'Rebuild Index Task';
```

With help from [MSDN Social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7d9513e3-ea0a-45fc-be24-a7d2a56cf0dc/querying-msdbdbosysssispackages?forum=sqlxml)

Salient Points

1. Need to cast the `packagedata` column through varbinary to xml
2. Use Cross Apply to apply the 'root node selector' xpath to all rows
3. To address namespaces, add aliases via `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`
4. Xquery such as `.value` needs to select scalars, so hence `(xpath)[1]`

Comment: Tested Point 1, and didn't return any results. When I removed the WHERE clause, I got back results from a sibling node (is that the right term?) which has a different executable type.

Comment: Oh, I think it's because the DTS:Executable I'm querying for is actually a child of another DTS:Executable node. I'm not seeing its siblings in the results, I'm seeing its parent and its parent's sibling. I'll add that to your answer.